# How to save results of OGRSpatialReference::AutoIdentifyEPSG()

Tags: gdal, ogr, api, c++, epsg

Not that I see the need to programmatically mass-convert shapefiles, but there *must* be a way to store the EPSG authority in a converted and auto-identified shapefile.

My little C++ program can use the GDAL API to ...

- read a ETRS89_UTM32 shapefile dataset via `GDALOpenEx()`,
- check that it isn't EPSG:32632 by calling `GetLayer(0)->GetSpatialRef()->GetAuthorityName()` and `GetAuthorityCode()`,
- convert the file to EPSG:32632 by calling `GDALVectorTranslate()`,
- `GDALOpenEx()` the resulting shapefile,
- realize that its SRS *still* doesn't contain an EPSG authority entry (why not, BTW?),
- `AutoIdentifyEPSG()` the SRS, and
- check that the EPSG code now is indeed 32632

-- and then what? If I call `GDALClose()` on my freshly converted shapefile dataset and re-open it, its SRS still shows up as WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N, without any AUTHORITY entries.

This might have something to do with this comment in `OGRLayer::GetSpatialRef()`:

> The returned object is owned by the OGRLayer and should not be modified or freed by the application.

So: just converting a shapefile to EPSG:32632 (either in the console via `ogr2ogr` or programmatically via `GDALVectorTranslate()`) doesn't set any EPSG entries in the SRS. Performing `AutoIdentifyEPSG()` on the SRS *does* set the correct authority, but I can't seem to save it to make it stick.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the hack I ended up using:

if the converted .prj file doesn't contain a node with the target EPSG code, I just overwrite it with the WKT definition returned by calling `OGRSpatialReference::exportToPrettyWkt()` on a SRS initialized by `OGRSpatialReference::importFromEPSG(<target EPSG code>)`.

HTH.